# Configure an Azure windows virtual machine using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform

I'm trying to learn infrastructure as code and for this I use Terraform.
I'm also trying to understand how to manage the VM configuration using Ansible.
With Terraform, I'm able to create an Azure Windows virtual machine without problems, but I'm trying to understand why Ansible is not able to connect via SSH to the virtual machine.
Unfortunately, all the examples that I have found talk about Linux virtual machines, but I need to create a Windows virtual machine instead.

This is the Terraform code used to create the VM

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "SSH"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Test"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "secgroup-assoc" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "runner" {
  name                  = "runner"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  size                  = "Standard_B2s"
  admin_username        = "runner_admin"
  admin_password        = "*****"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.network_interface.id]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = 64
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-smalldisk"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  connection {
    host        = self.public_ip_address
    user        = "runner_admin"
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    timeout     = "4m"
    agent       = false
  }
}
```

This is the inventory file for Ansible

```
[runners]
<VM public IP>    ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_user=runner_admin
```

and this is the Ansible playbook

```
- name: Install Dependencies
  hosts: runners
  tasks:
    - name: Install git
      win_chocolatey:
        name: git
        state: present
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you actually install an ssh server on the windows machine (either [Openssh or win32-ssh](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#windows-ssh-setup))? The most common connection type from ansible to windows is usually [WinRM](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#winrm-setup). There is a [full example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/vm-configure-windows?tabs=ansible) of how to create a Win host using ansible and connect to it. You can adapt for terraform.

Comment: Thank you @Zeitounator for the clarification.
The complex job now is how to automate the WinRM configuration. I found [this](https://www.unixarena.com/2019/04/ansible-configure-windows-servers-as-ansible-client-winrm.html/) post that explains how to configure WinRM using PowerShell. I will try to create a Powershell script to execute using Terraform.

Comment: This is all explained and automated through ansible in the example I gave you above...

Comment: Yes, you are right :)
Thank you again @Zeitounator

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a Windows Virtual Machine via SSH, you need to install SSH Server in your Windows VM.

As Windows VM does not have any default SSH unlike Linux VM

You can install OpenSSH server on your Windows VM.

Then you would be able to connect to your Windows VM via SSH using Ansible